# Laravel collection containing model to array

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, laravel-5.5

I have a Laravel Collection containing several User models.

```
Collection([
    User,
    User,
])
```

The model contains for example username, first name, last name, email, date of birth. I only need username, email, date and have it in an array like this.

```
array(
    array('jonhdoe', 'johndoe@example.com', '1-1-1970')
)
```

so that I can access it with

```
$username = $array[0][0]
$email = $array[0][1]
```

and not

```
$username = $array[0]['username']
$email = $array[0]['email']
```

I was looking at the Laravel helpers each or map, but somehow I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`only()` will return an array of specified columns only. And `toArray()` will transform the collection to array:

```
$collection->map(function($i) {
    return array_values($i->only('username', 'email', 'date'));
})->toArray();
```

Comment: If I look at the documentation of only() https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-only it looks like I can access the items from the model by the key, but I want to access it by it's number.

Comment: @Matthieu it's not clear. Please give some more details and show full collection.

Comment: I edited my question. Hope that shows better what I mean.

Comment: @Matthieu looks like a bad idea but if you really need it, use the `array_values()` as I've shown in the updated answer.

Comment: Why would this be a bad idea?

Comment: Because its more verbose and descriptive than some random numbers like `$array[0]['0']` vs `$array[0]['username']`. You could argue that the meaning is clear because you store it to `$username`, but this might not always true or necessary as you can just use the array + key directly.  Even the namin of `$array` is bad. Variable names should not reflect the type but the meaning of its content. 

Additional your code breaks when someday somebody decides to add another value to the array between `username` and `email` -> `$i->only('username', 'foo', 'email', 'date')`.

Comment: I had to leave away the toArray() at the end, but the rest of the code worked like a charm.

Comment: @commonsense the name of $collection and $array are there just as an example. In my code I use more meaningful names.
The line with this code is just lines above the function that uses it. But that is a library that I use and I can't control which input is needed. So nothing else to do than change my input.

Answer (score 0):

Use [toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-toarray)-

```
$collection_in_arrays = $collection->toArray();
```

> The `toArray` method converts the collection into a plain `PHP array`. If the `collection's` values are [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) models, the models will also be converted to `arrays`.